# Einstein's postulates <==> Minkowski space. In layman's terms

Tags: spacetime, special-relativity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Einstein's postulates <==> Minkowski space. (In layman's terms)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/einsteins-postulates-minkowski-space-in-laymans-terms)

In the spirit of Einstein's arguments using flashes of light, moving trains and mirrors; 
what is the best way to go between Einstein's postulates [[1](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Electrodynamics_of_Moving_Bodies)] of

1. Relativity: Physical laws are the same in all inertial reference frames.
2. Constant speed of light:  "... light is always propagated in empty space with a definite speed $c$ which is independent of the state of motion of the emitting body."

to Minkowski's idea [[2](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Space_and_Time)] that space and time are united into a 4D spacetime with the Lorentzian signature.

The argument can only use simple mathematics (algebra, geometry, a little calculus). I want an argument that a smart high school graduate would be able to understand.
None of the group theory and coset/homogeneous spaces of [Marek's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/einsteins-postulates-minkowski-space/12438#12438) to [my previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12435/429). (Although, if you do have a little knowledge of Lie algebras, you should go read Marek's answer and references now!).