# frames of reference

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, inertial-frames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help Me Gain an Intuitive Understanding of Lorentz Contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14362/help-me-gain-an-intuitive-understanding-of-lorentz-contraction)

Frames k and k' are inertial frames. Frame k' is moving at a velocity of magnitude v relative to frame k in the direction of the x-axis. there are rigid rods in each frame oriented along the direction of the relative velocity. Someone in frame k measures the rod that is stationary in k as having length L1 and the rod stationary in frame k' having a length L'2. What are the lengths of the rods measured by someone in frame k'?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is length contraction, the lengths of the first is $L1\sqrt{1-v^2}$, it gets contracted, while the length of the moving one is $L2/\sqrt{1-v^2}$, so that after contraction it gives the right answer. The details of the geometry is explained in my answer here: [What are the mechanics by which Time Dilation and Length Contraction occur?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/what-are-the-mechanics-by-which-time-dilation-and-length-contraction-occur) .