# Lorentz-like transformations of 1+1 dimensional Minkowski space

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers, education

Alice lives in 1+1 dimensional Minkowski spacetime.  Bob travels at a constant
velocity $v$ with respect to Alice.  When Alice assigns coordinates $(t,x)$
to an event, Bob assigns coordinates $F(t,x)$ to that event. I'll call $F$
*allowable* if it leads to physics that satisfies Einstein's postulates.
Obviously the Lorentz transformation $L$ is allowable.

Light-clock style arguments convince me of this:

> If $F$ extends to an allowable
> transformation on 2+1 dimensional Minkowsi spacetime, then
> the restrictions of $F$ and $L$ to the inside of Alice's future lightcone must
> agree.

This leads to two questions:

**Question 1:**  If I don't require $F$ to extend to a higher-dimensional
spacetime, must it still agree with $L$ inside Alice's future lightcone?

**Question 2:**  If $F$ does agree with  $L$ inside Alice's future lightcone,
must it agree with $L$ everywhere?

Some notes:

- I care about Question 1 because I want to derive the Lorentz
  transformation for students who have already been told that we will
  restrict our attention to 1+1 dimensional spacetime for simplicity.
  I'd therefore prefer not to invoke an additional spatial dimension.
  (Yes, there are all sorts of ways to justify this, including the fact
  that there is obviously more than one spatial dimension in the real
  world.  But that still seems at least mildly jarring given the initial
  setup.)
- Question 2 of course becomes trivial if we assume that $F$ must
  be linear, or even just rational.
  But I'd prefer not to
  make extra assumptions.
- For each question, if the answer is "yes", my followup question is:  "Is there an easy way to prove this with arguments at about the level of the light-clock stuff?"  If the answer is "no", then my followup question is "What are some minimal assumptions that could convert the answer to "yes"?
- I've held Bob's velocity fixed and asked for a transformation $F$.  I could instead ask for a family of transformations $F(v)$ depending on velocity.   This might or might not change the answers.
- Maybe there's enough mathematical vagueness in
  "Einstein's postulates" that these questions admit multiple answers.  I'll
  still be interested in those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my answer doesn't really answer your Questions 1 or 2,
these may help:

- For a formulation of 1+1-Minkowski without appealing to a second spatial dimension (e.g. a transverse light clock), one could use the Bondi k-calculus (which uses radar methods with light-signals).

  One could also use a "longitudinal light clock" and my related "rotated graph paper" method.

  Both are described in my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/689291/148184
  to [Time dilation clock experiment: what would happen if the clock were flipped 90 degrees?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276574/time-dilation-clock-experiment-what-would-happen-if-the-clock-were-flipped-90-d)
- It seems that your questions are seeking an axiomatic approach, with emphasis on what assumptions are progressively needed to Minkowski spacetime. The following may be enlightening:

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Robb (assorted works involving causal-ordering)
  - "On Lorentz transformations", A.D. Alexandrov,  Uspehi Mat. Nauk,5, 3 (37) (1950), p. 187.
  - "A Contribution to Chronogeometry" A.D. Alexandrov (1967). Can. J Math, 19, 1119-1128. https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1967-102-6
  - "Mappings of spaces with families of cones and space-time transformations",
    A.D. Alexandrov (1975),
    Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata volume 103, pages 229–257 https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02414157
  - "Causality Implies the Lorentz Group"
    E.C. Zeeman,
    J.Math.Phys. Vol 5, April 1964, p.490-493
    https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1704140
  - found in a google search...

    "On Finslerian extension of special relativity", A.E. Sagaydak, Z.K. Silagadze, Mod. Phys. Lett. A 37N17 (2022), 2250106
    https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217732322501061 and
    https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.12279

Comment: This solves my question #1.  I was groping toward something like what you call the Bondi-k-calculus, with Alice bouncing light signals off events both on and off Bob's worldline, but was missing the key observation that the "k-factor" from Alice to Bob must be the same as the k-factor from Bob to Alice; therefore I had one too few equations and couldn't get anywhere.  In retrospect, this should have been blindingly obvious (which might explain why I got a downvote), but without you, I wasn't seeing it.

Comment: With that extra equation, it seems to me that I can get everything from the k-calculus that I can get from light-clocks, without assuming an extra dimension.

Comment: As for Question 2, the problem with light-clocks is that to find the transform of (t,x), I have Alice hold her stick at angle ArcCos[x/t] to the ground; this only works for (t,x) in her future lightcone.  Bondi has the same problem; it only works for events Alice can eventually send lightsignals to.  But I think there is an easy fix in both cases; just assume Alice made all her measurements at an earlier time when (t,x) was still in her future.   There are some mild additional hypotheses needed to make this legit, but they seem less objectionable than just out-and-out assuming linearity.

Comment: @WillO Since it is known that Minkowski spacetime is an affine geometry, like Euclidean geometry and Galilean spacetime geometry, it might be helpful to also consider possibly analogous assumptions in the Euclidean and Galilean case. From this viewpoint, it seems to me, that there is often a heavier burden placed on special relativity, as if the Euclidean and Galilean cases are somehow treated as "given".

Comment: I take your point and I sympathize with it.  But I am sure that if I were teaching classical mechanics, I'd worry just as much about the same sorts of issues.