# Causality Assumption in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity

The Causality Assumption in Special Relativity states that,

*Any two admissible observers must agree on the temporal order on time.*

Intuitively this assumption states that cause must precede the effect. But how can we emphasize this in general? Are there systems which do not obey this Causality Assumption? Are there physical theories which do not have this assumption?

Comment: what do you mean be "admissible observers"?  and "temporal order" of what?   of events?   of spacelike or timelike events?

Comment: Admissible observers are two observers two are moving with a constant relative velocity w.r.t each other. Temporal order of timelike events.

Comment: ok, thanks.  so i'm confused as to your characterization of this as an "assumption" of special relativity rather than a consequence of it.  the fact that inertial observers will agree on the time-ordering of timelike separated events is a well-known consequence of the postulates of special relativity: c.f. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16353/why-is-time-order-invariant-in-timelike-interval